# How to find the number of subsets in a set without writing all of them out?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> How can you find the number of subsets in any set like $\{2, 4, 6, 8\}$ without writing out the subsets first including the empty set and the set itself?

I seriously need the shortcut to finding the number of subsets in a set without writing out every subset so I can find out the answers immediately.

Comment: There are $|\mathscr P(A)|=2^{|A|}$ subsets of a set $A$.

Comment: A set with $n$ elements has $2^n$ subsets.

Comment: Thanks for the info, bof and theage!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Comment: All right.  I will look very good, Joao!

Comment: I would like to say thank you to that person who make the edit to my question and my tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: An element is either in a subset or not. Now, given a finite set of $n$ elements, consider how many ways you can arrange a subset.

Comment: Okay, I will do that.  Now let's see.  If I have something like {2}, then the possibilities are the empty set and {2}, so there are 2^1 or 2 possibilities.  Now if I have something like {10, 15}, then the possibilities are the empty set, {10}, {15}, and {10, 15}, so there are 2^2 or 4 possibilities.  Now this is the final thing.  If I have something like {3, 4, 5}, then the possibilities are the empty set, {3}, {4}, {5}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}, and {3, 4, 5}, so there are 2^3 or 8 possibilities, so I guess the shortcut is to take the number of things there are and let them be an exponent of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Base case: We have the empty set as the set.  The only subset of the empty set is itself.  So, we have 1 subset for the empty set.

Recursion schema: Suppose that for for a set with n elements, the number of subsets it has is 2$^n$.  Then for a set with (n+1) elements, we have one more choice for whether or not an element belongs to a subset or not.  Since each element gives us 2 choices, we have twice the choices we had for all of the subsets of a set with n elements.  Thus, for a set with (n+1) elements we have 2$^{(n+1)}$ subsets.

Therefore, for a set with a crisp indicator function, it has 2$^n$ possible subsets.

Comment: Well, one thing I know is that the empty set is a subset of ANY kind of set.

Answer (score 0):

As probably hinted by now, perhaps you could prove your conjecture using induction? (was not sure if you needed a proof, not enough reputation to add onto an existing comment)